# solr : how to search for a tag in a specific field

Tags: solr

I want to perform a search for occurrence of specific tags in a field:

```
<field name="productTagValues" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

A document can have multiple tags. Eg.:

```
"productTagValues": [
      "Everyday Wear",
      "Double Chain",
      "Traditional and Imitation",
      "Gold Plating",
      "Metal Alloy",
      "Special Occasions or Gifts"
}
```

I want to retrieve all the docs that have a specific tag. Eg. `all the docs with Gold Plating as one of the tags`.

I tried using fq=productTagValues:Gold Plating. But it also returned docs that didn't have `Gold Plating` in the `productTagValues` field.

Could someone please help me with this

Comment: would it still return documents without the `Gold Plating` if you did `q=productTagValues:Gold Plating`?

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski: Among the top 30(that i am able to see), it returns the desired results. But numFound is far greater than expected

Comment: I'll write this as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, the solution was to do a query:

```
q=productTagValues:Gold Plating
```

instead of

```
fq=productTagValues:Gold Plating
```